# Input text being cutoff with overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I'm new to flutter so this may be a trivial problem, but I have a search box which contains an `TextField` and an Icon.

It works fine while the input text is less than the width of the input box, but once it exceeds that it seems to get chopped in half such that only the top half of it can be seen.

From what I understand Flutter is supposed to automatically deal with overflows. This is the build method for a generalised Input widget which is what I use along with the Icon in a Row. It's used within a `Row` but I don't believe that is the issue.

This is what it looks like when the text overflows.
[image: This is what it looks like when the text overflows]

```dart
return Expanded(
  child: TextField(
    autofocus: autofocus,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).cursorColor,
    maxLines: 1,
    controller: controller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      hintText: placeholder,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
    ),
    onChanged: (String value) {
      onChange(value);
    },
    onSubmitted: (String value) {
      onChange(value);
    },
  ),
);
```

This is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Lutetium-Vanadium/Music-Flutter) in case you want to see the contextual usage. It's used in `lib/routes/MainPage.dart` as well as `lib/routes/SearchPage.dart`.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue from your code.. Please provide code where we can reproduce it

Comment: There is a link to the github repo in the question, you can see the full source code there, but basically the given widget is placed in a Row along with an Icon, which is in a Container which is part of a AppBar actions.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it was being cutoff due to the `contentPadding` on the `InputDecoration`. For those of you who are facing the same issue, change `decoration` property to:

```dart
InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Removes padding
  isDense: true,                   // Centers the text
  border: InputBorder.none,
  hintText: placeholder,
  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
)
```